# QSslSocket proxy server (https) and certs. Handshake error

Tags: c++, qt, https, openssl

I'm writing a proxy server, http part is ready, but are having problems with https.
I created a certificate and private key (as I understood, without it will not work) in this way:

```
OpenSSL> req-x509-newkey rsa: 2048-keyout server.key-nodes-days 365-out server.csr
```

I did a simple QTcpServer that is passed a socketDescriptor to the created object on newIncomingConnection().
In constructor of my object I did:

```
    sock = new QSslSocket();
    connect (sock,SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(onQuery()));
    connect(sock,SIGNAL(disconnected()),this,SLOT(deleteLater()));
    connect(sock,SIGNAL(error(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)),this,SLOT(onError(QAbstractSocket::SocketError)));
    connect(sock,SIGNAL(sslErrors(QList<QSslError>)),this,SLOT(sltSslErrors(QList<QSslError>)));

...
Load key and cert
...
    sock->setProtocol(QSsl::AnyProtocol);
    QSslKey sslKey(key, QSsl::Rsa);
    QSslCertificate sslCert(cert);
    sock->setPrivateKey(sslKey);
    sock->setLocalCertificate(sslCert);
    sock->setSocketDescriptor(socketDesc);
    sock->startServerEncryption();
    if(!sock->waitForEncrypted(30000)) {
        qDebug()<<"wait for encrypted failed";
    }
```

On connect in console I see "wait for encrypted failed" and socket emited signal error() with QAbstractSocket::SslHandshakeFailedError.
Could you give advice on what else to do that would be to establish the ssl connection without error ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to call `setSocketDescriptor` before calling the `setPrivateKey` and `setLocalCertificate` methods.

Below is code that I've used to create a `HTTPS Server Socket`, extending `QTcpServer`.

```
void SslServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    QSslSocket *serverSocket = new QSslSocket;
    if (serverSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor)) {
        QFile keyFile(<sslKeyFileName>);
        if (!keyFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            delete serverSocket;
            return;
        }
        QSslKey key(&keyFile, QSsl::Rsa, QSsl::Pem, QSsl::PrivateKey);
        if (key.isNull()) {
            delete serverSocket;
            return;
        }
        keyFile.close();
        serverSocket->setPrivateKey(key);
        // to prevent asking for client certificate.
        serverSocket->setPeerVerifyMode(QSslSocket::VerifyNone); 
        serverSocket->setLocalCertificate(<certificateFileName>);
        serverSocket->startServerEncryption();
        if (serverSocket->waitForEncrypted(3000)) {
            // this will emit a newConnection() signal
            addPendingConnection(serverSocket);
        } else {
            qDebug() << "Encryption Failed.";
            delete serverSocket;
        }
    } else {
        delete serverSocket;
    }
}
```